# Space Opera Book Series with the main premise of a black hole thing that inhabits another world, allowing telekinetic powers

Tags: story-identification, books, space-opera

A black hole thing was created by an alien species and it inhabits a whole world in it that can fulfill a person's desires through the manipulation of space-time or creating multiple dimension layers. I forget the specifics, but it basically requires a lot of energy to run. This creates a black whole phenomenon, where it engulfs all the energy around it to feed whatever the person inside it has imagined. Essentially they get telekinetic powers (or mind bending reality powers of some sort).

A space exploration ships gets engulfed inside this black hole and I remember there being two planets that one of each ship crash lands on. They can't use their technology because it seems to go haywire in this world, and there are these monster things that are already there that seem to take over a organism's mind, that they have to fight against.

I don't quite remember what happens with one of the planets, but on the other planet, they get everything figured out and establish a civilization of sorts with telekinetic powers and a force to fight against these parasite things. On comes this villager guy, who turns out has extraordinary telekinetic powers and can do lots of things that amaze other people. He becomes a legend, basically Hercules, but with telekinetic powers.

The story reveals that the really strong guy had powers so strong he sent out his entire life in memory to the outside world, which some guy on the other end receives and becomes some sort of messiah, and they start a religion out of it because they want to travel to this world since they think it's some sort of tangible heaven.

There's obviously a lot more to this as it is a book series, but I think I gave enough of a intro and my memory of this series is all over the place, but I hope someone can point me in the right direction because it was a good book series that I'm thinking about reading again.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this book, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall any details about the cover?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That sounds like ["The Void Trilogy"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_Trilogy) by Peter F. Hamilton

> What was formerly believed to be a supermassive black hole at the centre of the Milky Way is revealed to be an artificial construct, known as the Void. Inside, there is a strange universe where the laws of physics are very different from those we know. It is slowly consuming the other stars of the galactic core—one day it will have devoured the entire galaxy.

> In AD 3320, a human member of the Commonwealth, Inigo, begins to have dreams of the wonderful existence inside the Void. His dreams inspire the disaffected, who desire to travel into the Void, where their every wish will be fulfilled. By AD 3456, the pseudo-religious Living Dream movement exceeds 5 billion members, organizing the followers into a powerful political force. Other star-faring species fear their migration will cause the Void to expand again thus devouring the galaxy. They are prepared to stop the pilgrimage fleet no matter what the cost.

> The Dreaming Void is broken into two distinct sections. The first follows Edeard, a young boy who lives inside the Void on a planet called Querencia, the subject of Inigo's dreams.

The monsters are from ["The Chronicle of the Fallers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicle_of_the_Fallers), which is set on a different planet inside the void.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely Void Trilogy set in Peter F. Hamilton's "Commonwealth Universe", namely "The Dreaming Void" (2007),"The Temporal Void" (2008) and "The Evolutionary Void" (2010).

Construct in the middle of galaxy where we would normally expect to find a black hole is The Void, immense construct left there by First Life who evolved first and were alone in the galaxy, so Void was their bid on evolving out of physical forms.
The guy with strong powers you mention is Edeard his life gets shared as a series of dreams by his relative Inigo, who is living life outside the void, and uses his dreams to start a religious movement "Living Dream" which is intent on emulating Edeard's lifestyle and ultimately making a pilgrimage to the Void.

Monsters you mention are named Fallers, species that also gets trap in the void. They use huge living ships to travel trough the galaxy and once they find a suitable planet, ships generate eggs, which are strong enough to fall on planet surface and trough pheromones draw in biggest lifeform they can, once the lifeform makes contact with the surface of the egg, it cannot be broken, unless the limb is severed. The egg then slowly consumes the victim and produces perfect replica, but a member of faller species, which are usually a lot stronger (and in the Void have stronger telekinesis).

They use nanobiotech to shape themselves in the form of dominant life form and ultimately replace them (they also eat their duplicated prey) but those parts aren't from Void trilogy but from the sequel duology "Chronicles of Fallers", namely "The Abyss Beyond Dreams"(2014) and "A Night Without Stars"(2016) which take part on different planet in the Void. Their slave species which has "defaults" which can be shaped in almost any form you want is present in Void Trilogy are called Genistars in Void Trilogy, or Mods on planet Bienvenido in "A night without stars"

Comment: Is this an AI-generated answer? If it is, have you checked the relevant books yourself to verify that these details are correct? AI-generated answers tend to get a lot of things wrong.

Comment: no it isn't  I' ve read this series more than 10 times over the years. I know it by heart